# Background thread - two network calls

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading

I have two methods in the completeOnboarding method and both of them have network operation which should be done in the background thread as follows. However, I am wondering if I am doing why `completion(true)` gets called first, how could I able to handle that issue?

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    self?.completeOnboarding( completion: { (success) in
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if success {
         print("success")
        } else {
         print("failed")
        }
     }
 })

func completeOnboarding(completion: @escaping(Bool) -> Void){

   // has network post operation
    classRegistration() {(success) in
      if !success {
        completion(false)
        return
      }
    }

    // has network post operation
    classLocation() { (success) in
      if !success {
        completion(false)
        return
      }
    }
  completion(true)
}
```

Comment: Presumably, `classRegistration` and `classLocation` are asynchronous methods, so they return right away

Comment: Yes, these are async methods. These both methods are making network call to the service.

Comment: Virtually identical to your https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67030741/dispatchgroup-logical-workflow

Answer (score 0):

The final completion(true) is not waiting for classLocation() and classRegistration() calls. If you have multiple network calls and you want to wait for all of them to finish you could (one approach) add them to a DispatchGroup and wait for that one to finish:

```
func dispatchAndWait(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    func networkOne(completion: @escaping (_ success: Bool) -> Void) {
        print("[DEBUG] Enter \(#function)")

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + Double.random(in: 0...3)) {
            completion(Bool.random())
        }
        print("[DEBUG] Return \(#function)")
        
    }
    
    func networkTwo(completion: @escaping (_ success: Bool) -> Void) {
        print("[DEBUG] Enter \(#function)")
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + Double.random(in: 0...3)) {
            completion(Bool.random())
        }
        print("[DEBUG] Return \(#function)")
    }
    
    // Create a DispatchGroup and add both calls
    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
    // Enter first network call
    dispatchGroup.enter()
    networkOne { success in
        print("[DEBUG] Complete networkOne with success: \(success)")
        // Exit first network call
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    }
    
    // Enter second network call
    dispatchGroup.enter()
    networkTwo { success in
        print("[DEBUG] Complete networkTwo with success: \(success)")
        // Exit second network call
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    }
    
    // notify gets called when all tasks have exited
    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
        completion()
    }
}
```

One more advise:

```
classRegistration() {(success) in
  if !success {
    completion(false)
    return
  }
}
```

will never complete in case of success==true, you should make sure that the completion is called on every path

```
classRegistration() {(success) in
  // ... do whatever needs to be done here
  completion(success)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Assuming classRegistration needs to succeed for classLocation to begin --

quick & dirty --

```
func completeOnboarding(completion: @escaping(Bool) -> Void){

   // has network post operation
    classRegistration() {(success) in
      if success {
        
        // has network post operation
        classLocation() { (success) in
            completion(success)
        }

      } else {
        completion(false)
      }
    }
}
```

a proper way (others include - NSOperations with dependency, Dispatch group)

```
func completeOnboarding(completion: @escaping(Bool) -> Void){
   
   let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "classname.serial")

   var proceedWithSuccess = true

   serialQueue.async {
       
       serialQueue.suspend() //run 1 operation at a time
   
       classRegistration() {(success) in
            proceedWithSuccess = success
            serialQueue.resume() //let next operation run
       }
   }
   
   serialQueue.async {
    
    guard proceedWithSuccess else { return } 

      serialQueue.suspend()

          classLocation() { (success) in

           proceedWithSuccess = success
           serialQueue.resume()
       }
   }
          
   serialQueue.async {
      completion(proceedWithSuccess)
   }
}
```

2. If you want classLocation() to fire even if registration fails - just get rid of guard statement above.

If it were up to me I'd use a custom NSOperation subclass for Async operation & explicitly mention dependency between operations but it needs a ton of boilerplate code (perhaps something to look into later); serial queue (or dispatch group from the other answer) oughta be enough for you in this case though.

Comment: You might have to declare the serial queue outside the function if it doesn't work - it should work as it is though.