# DispatchGroup logical workflow

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I am trying to implement `DispatchGroup` as follows, but if the first call returns `true`, then the second one returns `false`, then overall result will return `false`.

However, if the first call returns `false`, then the second one returns `true`, then overall result will return `false` which is not what I expected.

I want to return `false`, if any of the call returns `false`. How could I able to handle this issue?

```
 func storeInformation(id: String?, _ completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {
    guard
      let id =  id
    else {
      completion(false)
      return
    }
    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
    var groupResult: Bool = false
    dispatchGroup.enter()
    storeFeatures { success in
      if success {
        groupResult = true
      } else {
        groupResult = false
      }
      dispatchGroup.leave()
    }
    
    dispatchGroup.enter()
    storeClasses { success in
      if success {
        groupResult = true
      } else {
        groupResult = false
      }
      dispatchGroup.leave()
    }
    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
      completion(groupResult)
    }
  }

  private func storeClasses(_ completion: @escaping(Bool) -> Void) {
    postClasses { (error) in
      if let _ = error {
        completion(false)
      } else {
        completion(true)
      }
    }
  }

  private func storeFeatures(_ completion: @escaping(Bool) -> Void) {
    postFeatures { (error) in
      if let _ = error {
        completion(false)
      } else {
        completion(true)
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we look at your `storeClasses` and `storeFeatures`, we see that they are *not* really actions that return a Bool; they are inherently attempts to post something *that can fail*. Hence what you really want to know is not whether something returned `true` or `false` but whether or not it *failed*. That is what you really mean — and it is always better, in programming, to **say what you mean**.

Using the Combine framework, we can express that sort of behavior with unbelievable succinctness. When we have multiple asynchronous actions to perform simultaneously, that is a Merge. And if one of them fails, *the entire Merge fails*. In other words, the very thing you want to do is effectively automatic!

Imagine, for example, that we have expressed your post actions by wrapping them in deferred Futures of type `<Void,Error>`. And suppose we have methods `storeClassesFuture` and `storeFeaturesFuture` that produce those Futures. Then all you have to say is:

```
Publishers.Merge(storeClassesFuture(), storeFeaturesFuture())
```

That is literally all there is to it! If you subscribe to that Merge with a `sink`, then either it receives a `finished` completion or a `failure` completion. And guess what? It receives the `failure` completion *if and only if one or both of the post actions failed!* It receives the `finished` completion only if they both succeeded, which is *exactly* what you want to know.

As a test bed, here's a sample implementation of your `storeInformation` (I'm ignoring the String for purposes of the example):

```
var storage = Set<AnyCancellable>()
enum Oops : Error { case darn }
func storeInformation() {
    Publishers.Merge(storeClassesFuture(), storeFeaturesFuture())
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .sink { (completion) in
            switch completion {
            case .failure: print("at least one of them failed")
            case .finished: print("they both succeeded")
            }
            print("---")
        } receiveValue: { _ in }
        .store(in: &storage)
}
```

And just to act as a random test, here are two futures that can randomly succeed or fail:

```
func storeClassesFuture() -> AnyPublisher<Void,Error> {
    Deferred {
        Future<Void,Error> { promise in
            if Bool.random() {
                print("storeClassesFuture succeeded")
                promise(.success(()))
            } else {
                print("storeClassesFuture failed")
                promise(.failure(Oops.darn))
            }
        }
    }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
func storeFeaturesFuture() -> AnyPublisher<Void,Error> {
    Deferred {
        Future<Void,Error> { promise in
            if Bool.random() {
                print("storeFeaturesFuture succeeded")
                promise(.success(()))
            } else {
                print("storeFeaturesFuture failed")
                promise(.failure(Oops.darn))
            }
        }
    }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

And here's some sample output from calling `storeInformation` repeatedly:

```
storeClassesFuture succeeded
storeFeaturesFuture succeeded
they both succeeded
---
storeClassesFuture failed
storeFeaturesFuture failed
at least one of them failed
---
storeClassesFuture failed
storeFeaturesFuture succeeded
at least one of them failed
---
storeClassesFuture failed
storeFeaturesFuture failed
at least one of them failed
---
storeClassesFuture failed
storeFeaturesFuture succeeded
at least one of them failed
---
storeClassesFuture succeeded
storeFeaturesFuture succeeded
they both succeeded
---
storeClassesFuture succeeded
storeFeaturesFuture succeeded
they both succeeded
---
storeClassesFuture failed
storeFeaturesFuture succeeded
at least one of them failed
---
storeClassesFuture failed
storeFeaturesFuture succeeded
at least one of them failed
---
storeClassesFuture succeeded
storeFeaturesFuture succeeded
they both succeeded
---
```

As you can see, the logic you're after is perfectly expressed by the Merge of two failable Futures.

(This sort of thing is a very good reason to adopt the Combine framework instead of using DispatchGroup. I find that everything I used to do with DispatchGroup can be done better with Combine. This just happens to be a particularly clearcut instance.)

Answer (score 1):

You have an "AND" semantic here, so you should write that in your code:

```
let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
var groupResult: Bool = true // identity for AND
dispatchGroup.enter()
storeFeatures { success in
  groupResult = groupResult && success // here!
  dispatchGroup.leave()
}

dispatchGroup.enter()
storeClasses { success in
  groupResult = groupResult && success // and here
  dispatchGroup.leave()
}
dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
  completion(groupResult)
}
```

When each task finishes, you want to express the idea that

> The group result should be true iff the previous group result is true AND success is true